# page state management in maui blazor hybrid mobile app

Tags: blazor, maui, maui-blazor

i want to manage the page state like stack in the Maui Blazor hybrid mobile application. and also need to handle the navigation keys in the android system.

i already tried this with navigation manager but state is not managing. and also not able to handle the android navigation keys like (back button)

Comment: Have you try this: [Maui сhange navigation in BlazorWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71907264/19902734)?  *and also not able to handle the android navigation keys like (back button)* .  Use [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KknCe.png), I can hit it when I use back button.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as an answer, you can try the solution of this case: [Maui сhange navigation in BlazorWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71907264/19902734).

> and also not able to handle the android navigation keys like (back button) .

Use the [following code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KknCe.png), I can hit it when I use back button:

```cs
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    public override bool DispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent? e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode == Keycode.Back) && (e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.KeyCode);
        }
        return base.DispatchKeyEvent(e);
    }
}
```